# php json_encode has 2 keys for same object

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm using jQuery ajax to to fetch a json object from a php page.

At the php side I'm using

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($retval, $row);
}
```

and then

```
echo json_encode($retval);
```

to return it.

I'm getting a JSON at the client from jQuery ajax call as an array with two keys for the same value in each object. One key is the index position and the the other is the name. 
For e.g: each object in the array looks like the following:

```
0: "1234"
1: "2014-11-01"
hc_month: "2014-11-01"
hc_wi_fi_unique: "1234"
```

Any pointers on why I'm getting such results? (Is JSON_FORCE_OBJECT used for solving such problems)

PS: I don't have control of using mysqli or PDO over mysql. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a `json_encode` problem but `mysql_fetch_array`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

> The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By
>   using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative
>   and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative
>   indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get
>   number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

So `MYSQL_ASSOC` or use `mysql_fetch_assoc`, though I add the obligatory: **Get off of MySQL extension and use MySQLI or PDO**.

Comment: Works perfectly!. Thanks. And mysqli or PDO is not a choice I have as mentioned in the question. :) Will accept the answer in a minute.